# css selector for a element which has same class name

Tags: html, css

I need to find an element with CSS selector ...the element the same class name as the other element only difference is the parent div class
following are the html for the two elements with same class. I want to get the first node only so how will I differentiate

1.

```
<div class="ResponsiveContainer">
<div class="js-slide-panel-content display-block-m">
<div class="product-fulfillment-content copy-small module js-tab-ship product-buying-table-row-alt expanded">
<div class="tab-pointer tab-pointer-one hide-content display-inline-block-m"/>
<h3 class="fulfillment-logo-in-slide-panel">
<b class="js-product-fulfillment-default-location product-freight-default-location">Showing options for 94066</b>
<div class="js-product-fulfillment-table product-fulfillment-table bot-padding">
```

2.

```
<div class="js-pickup-slide-panel pickup-slide-panel-section product-buying-table-row-alt">
<div class="ResponsiveContainer">
<div class="js-slide-panel-content display-block-m">
<div class="product-fulfillment-content copy-small module js-tab-pickup product-buying-table-row-alt">
<div class="tab-pointer tab-pointer-two hide-content display-inline-block-m"/>
<h3 class="fulfillment-logo-in-slide-panel">
<b class="js-product-fulfillment-default-location product-freight-default-location">Showing options for 94066</b>
<div class="js-product-fulfillment-table product-fulfillment-table bot-padding">
```

So if i give css selector as `.js-product-fulfillment-default-location product-freight-default-location`  it is giving me both the nodes.
how will i get only the first node

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example has a difference (besides the root node) which can be exploited.  This should give you only the first node:

```
.expanded .product-freight-default-location
```